# How to implement Android EditText view Floating Hint in Material Design in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-edittext, android-support-library, material-design

I trying to implement float label for `EditText` using `android-support-design.jar` in eclipse.but `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout (Open Class, Show Error Log)` error message shown any solution ?

Comment: did you try the app-compat-lib ?

Comment: yes tried both app-compat-lib and android-support-design lib it throw run time exception.

Comment: Exception raised during rendering: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.

Comment: Get over with Eclipse
Google has decided Android Studio is all you need to make apps, and by the end of the year will no longer support the venerable but popular Eclipse IDE.